# Swapping the positions of my content and sidebar?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm not dead sure why, but I have creted two CSS classes `content` and `sidebar1`, with the intention of putting the sidebar on the right. But no matter what I do, when I put the `<div>`s in, the sidebar ends up on the left!

## My Code

### CSS

```
.container {
    max-width: 1500px;
    min-width: 1200px;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
.sidebar1 {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 1000px;
    float: right;
    border-left-color: #FFF;
    border-right-color: #FFF;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="content">

    <h1>Heading</h1>
    </div>

  <div class="sidebar1">
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) has many examples of CSS files that move a sidebar to left or to right - without changing the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you float more than one element right, subsequent elements in the DOM will appear to the **left** of the first element.

Although it might seem counter-intuitive, if you must float right, just switch the order of your elements.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar1">
      Sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="content">
         <h1>Heading</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w227h/)**

Comment: I know this is a practical solution but it kinda contradicts the idea of separating content and style.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Agreed, but is there a better solution if you **must** use `float: right` on two subsequent elements?

Answer (score 1):

Your order is the wrong way around -- first, your content div floats as right as it can, then, your sidebar does. (So basically, floating multiple things right will reverse the order.) Can you arrange for the sidebar to be before the content div in the source?

Comment: Another solution, just use float left instead of right and keep your HTML in it's place.  Generally float:left is more common for this reason, as it "reads" left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Why not float the content left and the side bar right then ? instead of both right which is what you currently have

e.g.

```
.container {
    max-width: 1500px;
    min-width: 1200px;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
.sidebar1 {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 1000px;
    float: left;
    border-left-color: #FFF;
    border-right-color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Because my content, if it is floated left, overlaps with another emelent with a higher `z-index` than the content.

Comment: @JayD2208: Your example doesn't include such an element. Maybe if you updated the example to demonstrate that part of the problem, people could suggest other solutions that might be interesting.

Comment: I agree with @RedGrittyBrick